# form values is not posting on button click, shows validation error

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In my code I want, if I checked que3 then it should fill all below data under que3 & post values to .php page. But here in code when I fill all details under qeu3 & click on submit button, instead of posting form values to next page, error shows in que4. I really don't know what happens in the code and why it gives a error in que4. I don't want it. can anybody please help me to solve it.

```js
function validate(){
 document.getElementById('msgerr').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('error5').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('error6').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('error61').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('error7').innerHTML='';
 document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML='';
if(!(document.getElementById('ques3').checked) && !(document.getElementById('ques4').checked)) {
document.getElementById('msgerr').innerHTML="select any one of them";
  return false;   
}
if(!(document.getElementById('ques3').checked) && !(document.getElementById('ques4').checked)) {
 document.getElementById('msgerr').innerHTML="select any one of them";
  return false;   
}

 <!--  for 3rd main que -->
if(document.getElementById('ques3').checked)
{
  var a = document.getElementById("list4");
 var option4 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
 var b = document.getElementById("list5");
 var option5 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
 var c = document.getElementById("list6");
 var option6 = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
 
 if(document.form.cloudapp.value == ''){
  document.getElementById('error5').innerHTML="fill all values";
  document.form.cloudapp.focus();
  return false;   
 }
 else if(option4=="none1"){
  document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML="Please select list1";
  document.form.list4.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(option5=="none2"){
  document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML="Please select list2";
  document.form.list5.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(option6=="none3"){
  document.getElementById("error5").innerHTML="Please select list3";
  document.form.list6.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(!(document.getElementById('thirdsubque11').checked)){
  document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML="Please select hosting type";
  document.form.thirdsubque11.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(!(document.getElementById('thirdsubque22').checked)){
  document.getElementById("error61").innerHTML="Please select hosting type";
  document.form.thirdsubque22.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(document.form.page1.value == ''){
  document.getElementById('error61').innerHTML="fill all values";
  document.form.page1.focus();
  return false;   
 }
 else if(!(document.getElementById('azure').checked)){
  document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML="Please select hosting type";
  document.form.azure.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(!(document.getElementById('rackspace').checked)){
  document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML="Please select hosting type";
  document.form.rackspace.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(!(document.getElementById('cloudho').checked)){
  document.getElementById("error6").innerHTML="Please select hosting type";
  document.form.cloudho.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(document.form.cludhost.value == ''){
  document.getElementById('error6').innerHTML="fill all values";
  document.form.cludhost.focus();
  return false;   
 }
}
<!--  over  -->
<!--  for 4th main que --> 
if((document.getElementById('ques4').checked) && !(document.getElementById('fourthsubque101').checked) && !(document.getElementById('external').checked)){
 document.getElementById('error7').innerHTML="select any one of them";
 document.form.fourthsubque101.focus();
 return false;   
}
 if(if((document.getElementById('ques4').checked)){

  if(!(document.getElementById('extweb1').checked) && 
         !(document.getElementById('social1').checked) && 
       !(document.getElementById('payment').checked))
  {
      document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML="select below  
       values";
      document.form.extweb1.focus();
      return false; 
  }
   }
<!--  over  -->

return true;
}
```

```css
div{
color:red;}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<div id="msgerr"></div>
<table border="1" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

<!--  3rd question   -->
<tr>
<td style="padding :0;"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="que3" id="ques3" onClick="thirdque();thirdqueUnchk();" />que3</td>
<td></td>
<td><div id="error5"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque1">
<td></td>
<td style="padding:0;">Total number of Cloud Apps to be tested</td>
<td style="padding:0;"><input type="text" size="30" id="cloudapp" name="cloudapp" placeholder="number of Cloud Apps to be tested" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque2">
<td></td>
<td style="padding:0;">Server side programming language</td>
<td style="padding:0;"><select style="width:70%;height:22px;" id="list4" name="cloudserverlang[]"> 
    <option value="none1" selected>None</option>
 <option value="31">php</option>
 <option value="32">Dot Net</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque3">
<td></td>
<td style="padding:0;">Browser side programming language</td>
<td style="padding:0;"><select style="width: 70%;height: 22px;" id="list5" name="cloudbrowselang[]">
     <option value="none2" selected>None</option>
  <option value="41">php</option>
  <option value="42">Dot Net</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque4">
<td></td>
<td style="padding:0;">Backend Database</td>
<td style="padding:0;"><select style="width: 70%;height: 22px;" id="list6" name="clouddblang[]">
     <option value="none3" selected>None</option>
  <option value="51">php</option>
  <option value="52">Dot Net</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque5">
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="thirdsubque11" name="amazon[]" value="Amazon Cloud Hosting" onClick="thirdsubque1();thirdsubque1Unchk()" />Amazon Cloud Hosting</td>
<td><div id="error6"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque51">
<td></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="Third party framework used" name="thirdframe[]" id="thirdsubque22" onClick="thirdsubque2();thirdsubque2Unchk()"/>Third party framework used</td>
<td><div id="error61"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque511">
<td></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of pages</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pages2" placeholder="Number of pages"  id="page1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque6">
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="azure[]" id="azure" value="Microsoft Azure Cloud Hosting" />Microsoft Azure Cloud Hosting</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque7">
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="rackspace[]" id="rackspace" value="Rackspace Cloud Hosting"/>Rackspace Cloud Hosting</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="thiredsubque8">
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cloudho[]" id="cloudho" onClick="thirdsubque3();thirdsubque3Unchk()" value="Other cloud hosting"/>Other cloud hosting</td>
<td><input type="text" id="cludhost" placeholder="Other cloud hosting" name="othrcloud" /></td>
</tr>

<!--  4th question   -->
<tr>
<td style="padding:0;"><input type="checkbox" value="que4" name="a[]" id="ques4" onClick="fourthque();fourthqueUnchk();" />que4</td>
<td></td>
<td><div id="error7"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourthsubque41">
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="select41[]" value="Android App" id="fourthsubque101" onClick="fourthsubque11();fourthsubque11Unchk()" />Android App</td>
<td><div id="error8"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourthsubque411">
<td></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="extweb[]" id="extweb1"  value="Calls any external web services"/>Calls any external web services</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourthsubque412">
<td></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="socialapp[]" id="social1" value="Uses any social media app internally" />Uses any social media app internally</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourthsubque413">
<td></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" id="payment" value="Performs payment transactions"/>Performs payment transactions</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourthsubque42">
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="iOSapp[]" value="iOS App" id="external" onClick="fifthque()" />iOS App</td>
<td></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" onClick="return validate()" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add if ques4 is checked or not before checking internal checkboxes for ques4. Put a if condition like :

replace

```
    if(if((document.getElementById('ques4').checked)){

     if(!(document.getElementById('extweb1').checked) && 
     !(document.getElementById('social1').checked) && 
   !(document.getElementById('payment').checked))
    {
        document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML="select below  
   values";
       document.form.extweb1.focus();
       return false; 
   }
  }
```

with

```
   if(document.getElementById('ques4').checked){

      if(!(document.getElementById('extweb1').checked) && 
             !(document.getElementById('social1').checked) && 
           !(document.getElementById('payment').checked))
      {
          document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML="select below  
           values";
          document.form.extweb1.focus();
          return false; 
      }
   }
```

Comment: if i click on submit buton without checking any checkbox , it goes to next page without doing validation.-@Vivek Gupta

Comment: At first if clicked submit,it redirect to next page, even though i put code to check whether any of those que3 & 4 are checked or not. & another error is its not validating que3 correctly. it mean while inserting values in que3 if clicked on submit, it should say fill other values but it won't.

Comment: @amigo I think you are completely replacing my script with yours. I have just put the code where I changed your script. you  need to replace that part only. i will edit my response

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is wrong
**Your below code checking the conditions for ques3 also**
    `if(!(document.getElementById('extweb1').checked) && !    (document.getElementById('social1').checked) && !(document.getElementById('payment').checked)){
    document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML="select below values";
    document.form.extweb1.focus();
    return false;

    }`
***Which should be checked only when selected que4***

Above code segment **must be within below if condition**
`if((document.getElementById('ques4').checked) && !(document.getElementById('fourthsubque101').checked) && !(document.getElementById('external').checked)){
}`

Comment: if put code inside in ques4 & click submit, it don't do validation . gives error in 2 div 1. in front of ques4 & 2. in front of android app, if checked ques4 only & clicked to submit- @Rahul Borole

Comment: Thanks for response @Rahul Borole.